# Access to timestamp in C - syslog ng

Tags: c, timestamp, raspberry-pi, syslog-ng

I'm working on a C project, with client/server syslog communication with a Rpi. I have been asked to use syslog ng and I'd like to access to timestamp.

From what I found [here](https://www.loggly.com/docs/timestamps/):

> Where the timestamp comes from depends on the type of log data you’re sending through.

Plus :

> If your data is forwarded by a syslog service, there is a timestamp embedded in the header that we can pull out and use.

So it's possible to pull out the timestamp. But how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use syslog-ng, it handles two different time stamps:

- the one, when the message was actually received
- the one included in the syslog message

These are accessible through macros. You can read more about it at https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.7-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.7-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#reference-macros

Comment: It seems to match to what I'm looking for ! Do you have an utilisation example ?

Comment: See for example: https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.7-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.7-guide-admin/html-single/index.html#configuring-macros